# Strange MySQL warning 1264 for valid DateTime value

Tags: mysql, datetime, warnings, mysql-error-1264

I have manually (GASP!) entered a MySQL command at the command line, and I received a Warning which I cannot even begin to understand.  (And before anyone says anything, yes, I KNOW: 1. Using the command line interface is not the best approach; 2. My table is NOT named "TABLE_NAME" and my column is NOT named "DateColumn" and my RecordID value is NOT really "1234"; 3. Maybe my column type *should* be TIMESTAMP, but for now, it's not.  Moving on....)

Attempting to enter a value for the date "July 26th, 2012 at 2:27 PM (GMT)", I keyed:

```
mysql> update TABLE_NAME set DateColumn="2012-07-26 14:27:00" where RecordID="1234";
```

I received:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.11 sec) 
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
```

So, I keyed:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                             |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'DateColumn' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Weird, I thought.  So I checked the table first to confirm the column (field) type:

```
mysql> describe TABLE_NAME;

+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
| DateColumn | datetime | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

BUT the value DOES get written properly to the database, and not truncated, AFAIK:

```
mysql> select * from TABLE_NAME where RecordID="1234";

+-----------------------------------------------+
| RecordID | Date_Column         | BlahBlahBlah |
+----------+---------------------+--------------+
|     1234 | 2012-07-26 14:27:00 | something..  | 
+----------+---------------------+--------------+
```

I've already searched StackOverflow.com for a solution.  I've already Googled for an explanation.  I've already read up at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html where it says:

```
    MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
```

I even had a slight suspicion that it had something to do with the date or time at which I was making the entry; so I will state that the server on which the database is located is on Pacific Daylight Time (GMT-8, except right now GMT-7 for DST); I am logged in (SSH) from a client on EDT (which should not matter); and I am storing all Date_Column values as GMT.  At the time I was entering the value "2012-07-26 14:27:00" all three dates were well AFTER that, on 7/30/12.  Not that it should matter -- I *should* be able to enter *future* dates without getting an error -- but thought it might be helpful for you to know.  So --

**WHY, OH WHY is "2012-07-26 14:27:00" an Out-of-Range Value?**

My MySQL client API version is 5.1.49.

This is the first time I've ever posted on StackOverflow.  Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: "The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'." So I don't see a problem with your value...

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @Throdne mysql> select version(); 
version() 
5.1.56-log

Comment: i'm not 100% sure if this is right, but you may want to look into "str_to_date" mysql command. I was looking for a solution last night and was unable to finish it. let me know if "str_to_date" works for you.

Comment: @Throdne: The solution that Markus suggested (below) seems to work, but so does yours:  
     
mysql> update TABLE_NAME set DateColumn=STR_TO_DATE("2012-07-26 14:27:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") where RecordID="1234";
     
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.34 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

Notice, however, the exactness with which I had to specify the parameters in the STR_TO_DATE function (%H, not %h, etc.)  I found a lot of help on that item at [http://dev.mysql.com/...#function_get-format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if it is converting it to some date format from string. That dateformat would then have too much precision which would be truncated. Try casting it to a datetime before assigning.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  Meanwhile: The Warning didn't say anything about truncating, only that the value was "out of range".  (Stumped.)

Comment: THIS WORKED -- NO WARNINGS!

mysql> update TABLE_NAME set DateColumn=CAST("2012-07-26 14:27:00" AS DATETIME) where RecordID="1234";
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

I still don't understand why it mattered, why the "precision" differed.  

But Thank You @Markus